# EF EntityObject dynamic property access

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic, interface, poco

I am new to Entity Framework and I am stuck with the following.

I have an existing database which I have imported into an EDMX model.

Some of my Entities share the same concept of "owner".

Each entity have a custom name for the "owner". Sometimes it is named "author", sometimes "owner", sometimes in French "auteur".

So I have implemented a simple Interface and created partial classes so my Entities could all share the same named concept of "owner".

```
public interface IAPIResource
{
    int owner { get; }
}
```

And my partial class for the entity BlogPost

```
public partial class BlogPost : IAPIResource
{
    public int owner { get { return auteur; } }
}
```

Now I want to use it in LINQToEntities query but LINQ tells me that's not possible because IAPIResource is not an entity type !

```
public List<T> GetFilteredEntities<T>(int owner, IQueryable<T> entities, MyDBContext db)
{
    return entities.Where(e => ((IAPIResource)e).owner == owner).ToList();
}
```

I have tried with Reflection (`.GetType` and `.GetProperty` and `.GetValue`) but LINQ does not support that either.

I have tried with POCOs as well, but no much luck.

And I don't want to modify my DB model with abstract entities and so on.

Does anyone have a simple solution without diving into LINQ Expression ?

NB : the real query is much more complex, that's why I am not willing to use Expression.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework does not support an explicit cast to `IAPIResource`, but you don't need it, you should be able to just do

```
public List<T> GetFilteredEntities<T>(int owner, IQueryable<T> entities, MyDBContext db)
    where T : class, IAPIResource
{
    return entities.Where(e => e.owner == owner).ToList();
}
```

However, this does require that you map your `owner` property in the implementing classes. You currently have

```
public int owner { get { return auteur; } }
```

but that won't work, because Entity Framework won't see that `owner` and `auteur` are the same property. You do need to change this slightly; my personal preference would be to turn this around: make `auteur` a wrapper property for `owner` instead of the other way around. That way, you can continue using `auteur` in your code, and `owner` in queries.

Comment: Hi hvd, thank you for your answer. I might be missing something but I tried your workaround, but it does not work either. LINQ still tells me it cannot cast BlogPost into IAPIResource because it is not a primitive EDM type. You should notice that the ", class" in your code does not seem to be correct (I am using VS2010, .NET 4.0), so I dropped it.

Comment: @user1844726 Oops, sorry about that. The `class` is required, but I got the order wrong. Fixed.

Comment: I am trying to implement the "wrapper" that you suggested but I can't manage to figure out how to introduce it in my code. Can you give an example on how to implement it ? Is it a scalar property that I add in the EDMX entity BlogPost ? But then I cannot override it. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @NicolasFaugout Right now, you have `public int owner { get { return auteur; } }`; instead, I'm suggesting you rename the `auteur` property in the EDMX to `owner`, and add `public int auteur { get { return owner; } }` (in other words, switch `owner` and `auteur`). The property that comes from the EDMX will then automatically implement `IAPIResource.owner`.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. But I can't do that this way because I reality, I have 2 properties in my interface that I want to bind to the same EDMX entity property `auteur`. `public int owner { get { return auteur; } }` and `public int author { get { return auteur; } }`. Because some of my entities do implement the difference between owner and author but some do not, like BlogPost. Do you have any clue on how to deal with that new problem ? Sorry to show it only now.

Comment: @NicolasFaugout In that case, sorry, but Entity Framework simply doesn't support that, as far as I know. The only way I can think of to get that working is to use some form of expression tree rewriting, so that `x.owner` is replaced by `x.auteur` before Entity Framework sees it. But that's fairly complicated...

Comment: Thank you @hvd for your time and answers. I think I will simply add a new column in the BlogPost table to fit the need of having 2 columns mathcing owner and author. And I will use the Interface the way you advised me. Thanks again.